# If you make a steel rod from here to Alpha Centauri and move it, will the movement appear there instantly?

Tags: special-relativity, velocity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible for information to be transmitted faster than light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/is-it-possible-for-information-to-be-transmitted-faster-than-light)

imagine this theoretical situation:
You have make an extremely long piece of steel (or anything really) one end is placed on earth the other is all the way at Alpha Centauri, 4ly away.
Here on earth the end is hanging loosely, on Alpha Centauri there is a bell at the end of the rod. Now if you move our end straight in the direction of AC will the bell there ring instantly ? Or will it be slower/same as speed of light.
If I take make it small scale, for example moving a steel rod with a bell on the end, I can't imagine that there would be a delay, but of course the speed of light is the limit, so what could cause the delay ? Thanks for explanation.
My very sketch:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/221/steelrod.png/

Comment: Yeah, it's an exact duplicate.