# How fast does the force of pulling a straight rope propagate along the rope?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves

Is it instantaneous or does it somehow propagate like a wave along the particles of the rope ?

Comment: It propagates at the speed of sound in the rope. I'm commenting rather than answering because I'm sure this is a duplicate. I'll see if I can find the duplicate I'm thinking of.

Comment: Aha, see [What “propagates” a force through the rest of a solid?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114397/what-propagates-a-force-through-the-rest-of-a-solid)