# Here's a way to transmit data faster than the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible for information to be transmitted faster than light by using a rigid pole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/is-it-possible-for-information-to-be-transmitted-faster-than-light-by-using-a-ri)

Assume there is a long rod or a string connecting two points separated by a distance of several light years. It will take light several years to travel, but by a simple pull or push of the string or rod we can transmit date in binary format, what do you think?

Comment: No, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2175/

Comment: Another identical question is http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21122/373 . (Shameless plug of my own answer : you can even derive a quantitative bound on the elasticity of the rod/string from relativity http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/21123/373 )

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not true. The time it takes for the rod to move will be much slower than if you send a light pulse from one end of the rod to the other. The rod moves because all its atoms move in a certain direction. The speed in which the atoms move and signal for the others to move is much slower than the speed of light. It is counter-intuitive because most rods we are dealing with are SHORT.