# do information travels faster than light?

Tags: general-relativity, visible-light

Suppose a long rod of length 6 lakh kms is subjected to movement at one end,does it move immediately or not at another end?

Comment: [There are no rigid bodies in relativity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48392/50583).

Comment: See also: [Is it possible for information to be transmitted faster than light by using a rigid pole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/is-it-possible-for-information-to-be-transmitted-faster-than-light-by-using-a-ri)

Comment: There are no rigid bodies, in relativity or otherwise (in the real world).