# Are John Norton's and Wolfgang Rindler's notions of "inertial frame (in special relativity)" equivalent?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

Among the (several) descriptions of an *"inertial frame"* (in the context of the Special Theory of Relativity),
those by [John Norton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_D._Norton) and by [Wolfgang Rindler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Rindler) appear especially concise:

- [*"In special relativity, an inertial frame of reference is a congruence of timelike geodesics."*](http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/papers/decades.pdf),
  John D. Norton, *"General covariance and the foundations of general relativity: eight decades of dispute"* (1993), p. 837

and

- [*"An inertial frame is simply an infinite set of point particles sitting still in space relative to each other."*](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Special_relativity:_kinematics#Galilean_and_Lorentz_transformations),
  Wolfgang Rindler (2011), Scholarpedia, 6(2):8520, *"Special relativity: kinematics"*.

**Are these two descriptions equivalent ?**
(even considering their brevity ...)

Specificly:
Given a [congruence $\mathfrak C$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(general_relativity)) of timelike geodesics in a flat region of spacetime,
i.e. (a spacetime-filling) family $\mathfrak C \equiv \{ \mathcal P_n \}$ of [world lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line#World_lines_in_special_relativity) which are

- each timelike,
- each geodesic (i.e. each straight in terms of Lorentzian distance, resp. Synge's world function, resp. spacetime intervals),
- non-intersecting (such that there is no event belonging to two or more world lines) and
- space(time)-filling (such that each event of the given region belongs to exactly one world line)

are any two of those world lines necessarily "sitting still" (or "running in parallel") to each other, in the sense that

$\forall \, \mathcal P_a, \mathcal P_b \in \mathfrak C, \forall \varepsilon_j, \varepsilon_k \in \mathcal P_a \, : $
$\exists \, \varepsilon_u, \varepsilon_v, \varepsilon_x, \varepsilon_y \in \mathcal P_b :$
 $s^2[ \, \varepsilon_j, \, \varepsilon_u \, ] = s^2[ \, \varepsilon_j, \, \varepsilon_v \, ] = s^2[ \, \varepsilon_k, \, \varepsilon_x \, ] = s^2[ \, \varepsilon_k, \, \varepsilon_y \, ] = 0$ and
 $s^2[ \, \varepsilon_u, \, \varepsilon_v \, ] = s^2[ \, \varepsilon_x, \, \varepsilon_y \, ] \neq 0$

?

Comment: In my opinion, the Rindler quote is incomplete since there's no explicit reference to geodesic motion---being at relative rest is not enough.

Comment: @robphy: "_the Rindler quote [...] being at relative rest is not enough_" -- Clearly Rindler's phrase "sitting still in space relative to each other" requires/presumes further definition. But outright, it appears distinctly named from just "being pairwise non-intersecting (a.k.a. non-coincident)", and different from just "being pairwise rigid", e.g. in the sense of [chronogeometric rigidity (Synge, GR, p. 108)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/106210/12262).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that not only are the definitions not equivalent, they are not even correct. A **frame** of reference means the reference *matter* which is used to define a coordinate system. For example we talk of the Earth frame, or if we are in a car, we will use the car as a reference frame. Norton's definition does not even refer to reference matter, but only to the *mathematical* construct of a geodesic, and Rindler does not refer to actual matter, but to an idealisation which only exists in thought.

Notwithstanding whether the definitions are correct, the fact that one is purely mathematical and the other invokes a notion of physical matter means that they are not equivalent. Mathematics is distinct from physics. A frame of reference is the means by which one relates the mathematical structure of relativity to physical observation, and depends for its definition on the physical structure which one uses as the basis for measurement.

Another issue is that the concept of a geodesic is only needed in general relativity. There is no point in using it in special relativity in which the geodesics are simply straight lines.

It is perfectly possible to give a succinct definition of an inertial frame without using mathematics to create the kind of obfuscation seen in these "definitions". This requires only the application of Newton's first law. For precision one should first define

- An **inertial object** is one such that, in any reference frame, the effect on
  its motion due to contact interactions with other matter is negligible.

Then one defines

- An **inertial reference frame** is one in which inertial bodies remain at rest
  or in uniform motion.

These definitions apply in the general theory of relativity, not just the special theory. They apply locally (an inertial frame is a local concept), and one should recognise that special relativity only applies to physics as local approximation.

Comment: "_A **frame** of reference means the reference **matter** [...]_" -- Allright (preliminary score: +1), though I'd say: it means a set of material, identifiable participants and their mutual geometric (incl. kinematic) relations **or** some equivalent. "_Norton's definition does not even refer to reference matter [...]_" -- I'd accept "a timelike curve" as suitably equivalent to "a point particle", etc. "_Newton's first law [...] effect on motion due to contact interactions_" -- I've focused on Norton's and Rindler's definitions for being purely geometric/kinematic. [contd.]

Comment: "_Then [...]: An inertial reference frame is one in which inertial bodies remain at rest or in uniform motion._" -- Apparently, that's not "_the reference **matter**_" as such, but something, "_in which_" it's characterized. (Preliminary score: 0.) Anyways: Your present answer version is utterly missing what I was hoping to learn from asking my question ... I might rephrase:  Given two **distinct** timelike geodesic congruences in the same spacetime region, are they guaranteed **disjoint**? (Given two **distinct** sets of "particles sitting still ...", **they are disjoint**.)

Comment: Yes, the particles in Rindler's definition follow a congruence in Norton's. This does not alter the facts that particles are not a congruence, that neither is a concise definition, because both require elaboration before they make sense, and that both miss the point of what a reference frame actually is.

Comment: btw, a reference frame does not have kinematic relations, since kinematic relations are defined relative to it. One might say the same about geometric relations, since geometry depends on measurement, and measurement is relative to the reference frame. One can define minimal conditions for a reference frame, e.g. an origin, a means of measuring time, a ruler, and three spacial axes, but that is, in itself, somewhat less than geometry. When I say reference matter, I do indeed mean "material, identifiable participants".

Comment: "_Yes, the particles in Rindler's definition follow a congruence in Norton's. [...] particles are not a congruence_" -- Fair enough: equivalence is not identity. "_both [Norton's and Rindler's descriptions] require elaboration_" -- Sure. Which word or which phrase doesn't?? (Among the few exceptions: the words "same" and "distinct".) "_both miss the point [...]_" -- I beg to differ. (And perhaps at least Norton, still, too.) [contd.]

Comment: "_btw, a reference frame does not have kinematic relations,_" -- Certain members of certain reference frames do have nontrivial kinematic relations, i.e. they are not even rigid wrt. each other: for instance, among the members of a "rotating but asymptotically inertial" frame one member close (but not quite at) the "center of rotation", and one "much further outwards". "_minimal conditions for a reference frame_" -- Sure: timelike, non-intersecting, spacetime-filling. **And**: without horizons.

Comment: You need rigidity *before* you can define geometry or kinematics. Nothing rotates relative to itself; reference frame must be defined *before* inertial reference frame. Horizons have no role in SR; inertial reference frames are necessarily local. Rindler attempts to define a reference frame without rigidity, but he *assumes* that "sitting still" makes sense without first defining coordinates through physical measurement. It doesn't, as illustrated by comoving coordinates in GR, which satisfy both definitions but are not an inertial frame

Comment: "_You need rigidity before you can define geometry or kinematics._" -- Elaborating the "rotating but asympt. inertial" frame: it contains (among many, many others) members $A$, $B$ ("near the center") and $F$ ("far off") such that $F$ finds alternatingly pings wrt. $A$ within (a.k.a. shorter than) pings wrt. $B$, or pings wrt. $B$ within pings wrt. $A$. Thus $A$, $B$, $F$ are not rigid wrt. each other. (Strict inertial frames don't contain such triples.) And hence require "no horizons".  "_Horizons have no role in SR_" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates#The_Rindler_horizon

Comment: "_comoving coordinates in GR, which satisfy both definitions but are not an inertial frame_" -- My OP question specifies a flat region; viz. SR. And it is (supposed to be) stated coordinate-free; therefore any subsequent assignment of coordinates is without consequence. "_Rindler [...] assumes that "sitting still [w.r.t. e. o.]" makes sense [...]_" -- I take that as: "being triplewise rigid, in a flat region". And again: Therefore distinct spacetime-filling sets "sitting still [w.r.t. e. o.]" are strictly disjoint; while distinct "geodesic congruences" are not necessarily disjoint.

Comment: I just wrote: "_I take Rindler's "sitting still relative to e.o." as: "being triplewise rigid, in a flat region"._" -- Sorry, that's incorrect (too weak). Appropriate for the purpose of the OP (and sufficient for concluding "if distinct, then necessarily disjoint") is instead: I take Rindler's "sitting still relative to e.o." as: "being triplewise rigid, in a flat region, and each sitting still individually (a.k.a. unaccelerated)". (This can be expressed rigorously in terms of spacetime intervals between events which make up the paths of participants, whose values are given in a flat region.)