# Information faster than light?

Tags: faster-than-light, information

Imagine that you have two typewriters on the other side of the galaxy. Their typebars are connected by ropes (stretched to the maximum), so anything you type will instantly appear at the second typewriter. 
Are the sentences information? If so, why not send information faster than light? If not, I'd at least ask if such a transfer is actually immediate.

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible for information to be transmitted faster than light by using a rigid pole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2175/)

Comment: The link I've suggested uses a rigid rod rather than a string, but the same argument applies. The tension in the string propagates at the speed of sound (in the string) so when you press a button on typewriter A it doesn't immediately type a letter on typewriter B.

Answer (score 1):

Stresses in the ropes do not propagate instantaneously - the velocity of sound in the ropes is limited.