# Maximum speed in water

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, water, refraction, speed

Is there a limit of maximum speed in water? Is it a finite value or the speed in water can take any possible value?

Comment: Hi Anjul. Are you asking if there is a maximum speed like the speed of light, or a practical speed limit e.g. because the water will vaporise if you try and move too fast through it?

Comment: I am asking about maximum speed limit just like speed of light in vacuum.

Comment: Do you mean the speed of a macroscopic object (like a submarine or a torpedo) moving in water?

Comment: Nowhere i said the body to be macroscopic or microscopic.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum speed in water is the speed of light in vacuum i.e. $c$.

The speed that light travels in water is less than $c$. It is $c/n$, where $n$ is the refractive index. However this is not any fundamental limitation. It is because light interacts with the electrons present in the water and the interacting light/electron system travels slower than $c$. For more on this see [Can speed of light be $c$ in air or other medium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235568/can-speed-of-light-be-c-in-air-or-other-medium) or search this site for many other questions on this subject.

We know that $c/n$ is not the maximum speed in water because subatomic particles can travel faster than $c/n$ in water. This is the origin of [Cherenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation).