# Superluminal Thought Experiment

Tags: special-relativity, rotation, faster-than-light

If I had a weightless, indestructible rod that was 1,145,915,590 meters long and I moved it 15° would the end of the rod go faster than the speed of light? (Assuming it's path is unobstructed.)

Calculations: $$arc length=2\pi R\left(\frac{C}{360}\right)$$ The angle is an arbitrary value which I chose to be 15° and the arc length is needed to be $3*10^8$ meters because I want it to move that in one second to exceed the speed of light. $$ 3*10^8=2\pi R\left(\frac{15}{360}\right)$$ $$R=1,145,915,590$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible for information to be transmitted faster than light by using a rigid pole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2175/)

Comment: @JoshuahHeath I looked awhile to make sure it wasn't a duplicate but yeah that essentially answers my question, thanks.