# What will happen if a stick and a beam of light is to race

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

I don't know whether the question is asked before on not on this website as I can't found it anywhere so I have to ask.
What will happen if a place a long stick with a length of a light year. Rather othe dimensions not matter just the sri k is a s long as a light year. Now I have placed a switch just in one end of the stick 1 cm apart. And the other end is on earth. Now my question is that what will happen if I push that stick and send a beam of light simultaneously toward thar stick who will win. The stick or the beam.
I know the light will win but can you explain the phenomenon.[image]

Comment: Are you including reaction time? Or you think you are quicker than Bruce Lee? Then, of course, how fast will you be moving the stick?

Comment: Let's talk about a hypothetical condition where I can do it with a force which is equivalent to move the stick with the speed of light *C*

Comment: Then light still beats the stick because of your reaction time, or are you about to make an assumption for that as well?

Comment: Ahh can you explain more deeply what is a reaction time

Comment: I'll let you do some research for that...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible for information to be transmitted faster than light by using a rigid pole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2175/)

Comment: @Solarmike Apart from reaction time, the stick isn't infinitely rigid, and it can't transmit a pulse faster than the speed of sound in whatever material the stick's made from. See the linked duplicate suggestion.

Comment: @PM2Ring the OP did not make that assumption about rigidity... Ahh, shame.

Comment: @SolarMike Questions about infinitely rigid poles, like questions about spaceships traveling at lightspeed, are off-topic due to being about non-mainstream physics. ;)