# Is it possible to rotate a very very long (almost infinite) and rigid pole such that its end reach the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light

$v=\omega r$ relation shows that even with a fixed $\omega$ and large $r$, the end of the pole can be rotated at a high speed. So if I make pole sufficiently long such that $v=c$, will it be possible to create such a scenario? The answer would be obviously no, but how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible for information to be transmitted faster than light by using a rigid pole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2175/)

Comment: @Prasoon Vishwakarma: not really the same question, but anyway theoretically not possible, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox