# Speed of light vs Tug of war

Tags: speed-of-light, string, faster-than-light, causality, information

Suppose there's a "theoretical rope" that's 299 792 459 meters long in empty space.

[image: tow]

The speed of light is 299 792 458 m/s.

Is it possible that if the rope is "tugged" on one end, the other end experiences an effect within < 1 second?

Comment: This is basically the same as [Is it possible for information to be transmitted faster than light by using a rigid pole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2175/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible for information to be transmitted faster than light by using a rigid pole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2175/)

Comment: Only 10 years too late! Didn't realize the concept was discussed earlier. Thanks.

Comment: look up "speed of sound"