# What's the speed of force?

Tags: forces, acoustics, faster-than-light, causality, speed

Brain storm:

Suppose we have a perfect lever, which has 0 quality, and perfect rigidity. It is long enough that can reach Proxima Centauri from the earth.

Someone push one side of lever from Proxima Centauri, immediately, the person from the earth will get the force. That means the force speed is infinity. With this way, information can be transferred via the lever immediately.

In real world, what the force speed will be for quality>0, and not perfect rigidity? Roughly, speed will be bigger for smaller quality lever, and speed will be bigger for high rigidity thing.

My question, is there any research on this area?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible for information to be transmitted faster than light by using a rigid pole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2175/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question, is there any research on this area?

The accepted main stream physics is that [nothing goes faster than the speed of light.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) This has been accepted as an axiom because it has been verified in a huge number of experiments.

The force you envisage is composed of electromagnetic forces transferred atom by atom on a rigid arm, and electromagnetic forces move with the velocity of light. The impulse cannot be faster then c, slower, yes.