# Why can't two charged particles know about each other's presence instantaneously?

Tags: electromagnetism

Why can't two charged particles know about each other's presence instantaneously? Does such a state of affairs produce contradictory or counter intuitive results?

Comment: See [Quantum entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement), so it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

One of the fundamental properties of nature is the fact that information cannot be transferred faster than light. The force carrier for electrodynamic interactions is the photon. When two charged particles interact with each other, the interactions have a time delay equal to the amount of time light would need to travel between them.

The answers on this question elaborate well on the weird results that come along with faster than light travel/communication: [How does faster than light travel violate causality?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52249/how-does-faster-than-light-travel-violate-causality)